# Material icon inside search text in angular JS

Tags: css, angularjs, textbox, icons, angular-material

I want the search icon to be inside of the search box but it is showing below it. 
Here is the code,

```
<section class="example">
            <section class="search-container">
                <input  type="search" id="sampleSearchInput" ><i class="material-icons">search</i>
            </section>
        </section>
```

CSS code-

```
input[type="search"] {
    padding-right:32px;
}

.search-container {
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    margin-left:55%; 

 }

.search-container > input[type="search"] + span {
    position:absolute;
    top:12px;
    right:10px;
}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this you your css

```
.material-icons{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```